# MySql Query Join 3 tables and grouping 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-concat

So I have the below database structure

```
TABLES ------- Columns
person:       id, name, salary, address
group:        id, name    
person_group: person_id, groud_id
```

So here is my query which is used to get all persons along with the groups they are associated with

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
group_concat(g.name) as groups 
FROM person_group pg, group g, person p
WHERE pg.group_id = g.id AND pg.novel_id = n.id
GROUP BY ng.person_id
```

So this query gives me data like

```
 id     name    groups
 2345   John    Admin, SuperAdmin, RedHat
```

But the problem is: if that person doesn't belong to any group, the query doesn't return that person!

Any would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

That is exactly your problem here.  When you are writing more than one table in the `FROM` clause, you should be thinking "what type of `JOIN` do I need".  If you had that thought, you would immediate realize that you need an outer join to do what you want:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, group_concat(g.name) as groups 
FROM person p LEFT JOIN
     person_group pg
     ON pg.person_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     group g
     ON pg.group_id = g.id 
GROUP BY p.id, p.name;
```

If you don't know what an outer join is, then that is all the more reason to use the proper, explicit syntax, so you can learn.

Comment: So what kind of join did I use my query(in question)? & How would you write the above query(in the question) using JOIN syntax? Also, why do I need to group by name? Is there any difference in performance?

Comment: @ngoa . . . Your query is the same as removing the `left`.  You are specifying `CROSS JOIN`s, but in combination with the `WHERE` conditions, they are effectively `INNER JOIN`s.